# How to make a column non-editable in Kendu UI Grid With Row template?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dataviz

[http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/s7ZCV/15/,](http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/s7ZCV/15/)
the above link is the simple example of Kendo grid with row template.All I wanted to do is make a specific column non-editable. the usual way is just define a model and further inside fields add editable False to the required field. i just wanted to know is there any other way to make a column editable as false because i dont want to add one more model in kendo as I am using models in entity level and Jay-data Level.

`var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: records,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "foo",
            fields: {
                foo: {type: "number"},
           CostCategoryAbv: {type: "string",editable:false},  // i dont want this
                VendorName: {type: "string"}
            }
        }

    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing a lot of work with the Kendo Grid using MVC.  I've been getting around this by using a custom popup editor.  The editor only allows the user to modify the fields that I want them to.  Another way of getting around this is by changing the controller so that any user edit does not modify the field when the data source is updated.  I know that the code provided is not using C# or MVC, but I hope this helps.  I think you may be able to modify the save method so that it only saves select fields.